# MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I want to add a row to a database table, but if a row exists I want to update the row. But I don't know how to format this query.

```
values = (firstname, lastname, age)`

cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO  TABLE (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `Age`) VALUES (%s %s %s) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE FirstName=VALUES(FirstName), LastName=VALUES(LastName), Age=VALUES(Age)''', values)
```

ERROR Message

```
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting your `,`between the values:

```
values = (firstname, lastname, age)`

cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO  TABLE (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `Age`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE FirstName=VALUES(FirstName), LastName=VALUES(LastName), Age=VALUES(Age)''', values)
```